# How to write a reusable Application Insights function that groups the data?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

Consider the following KQL query:

```
datatable(Value:int, ts:datetime) [
    10, datetime(2022-03-30),
    20, datetime(2022-03-30),
    10, datetime(2022-03-31),
    20, datetime(2022-03-31),
]
| where ts == '2022-03-30'
| summarize count() by Value
```

I would like to save it as a function without the timestamp filter, of course. Suppose this function would be named `MyFunc`. It should accept the timestamp as a parameter and called like this:

```
MyFunc('2022-03-30')
```

[The Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/functions) implies it is possible to save a function with parameters, but I do not understand how exactly am I to define such a function.

So, what am I missing? How can we save a function with parameters? This way I could have a reusable function that does grouping.

**EDIT 1**

So I modified the code:

```
datatable(Value:int, ts:datetime) [
    10, datetime(2022-03-30),
    20, datetime(2022-03-30),
    10, datetime(2022-03-31),
    20, datetime(2022-03-31),
]
| where ts == p_ts
| summarize count() by Value
```

But when I am trying to save it, the dialog has no parameters:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Let me edit it. I will produce a minimal reproduction.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz - is it better?

Comment: Poking around quite a bit for this myself.  It seems that if you do this through a Log Analytics scope, you'll get the option for specifying parameters, but with Application Insights, it's just not there.  I don't know if there's a workaround or not, but haven't found out how to do this either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/functions):

> Classic Application Insights resources don't support parameterized
> functions. If you have a workspace-based Application Insights
> resource, you can create parameterized functions from your Log
> Analytics workspace. For information on migrating your Classic
> Application Insights resource to a workspace-based resource, see
> Migrate to workspace-based Application Insights resources.

Not sure what you have, but this was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a name for your parameter, and use it in your query (in this example I'll be using `p_ts`)

---

Here is the query, with the parameter:

```
range ts from now() to ago(24h) step -1h
| where ts >= p_ts
| summarize count() by bin(ts,4h)
```

---

Here is the function definition, including the `p_ts` parameter definition

[image: Definition]

---

Here are couple of invocation examples:

## 1.

[image: Default Parameter]

---

## 2.

[image: ago(10h)]